# Calculating averages of a vector with increasing size

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I have a rendering function that runs hundreds of times per second, and it tells me how many milliseconds each frame takes to draw.

I made a function to calculate the current render speed average of all the frames, which uses an std::vector  to hold all the previous frames.

However, every time I run my program the vector that stores the averages becomes huge and takes up an increasing amount of memory, along with slowing down my program by almost 10 times (draw speed).

Averaging function (please note I am a C++ beginner):

```
double average(std::vector<double> input_vector)
{
    double total = 0;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < input_vector.size(); i++)
        {
            total += input_vector.at(i);
        }

    return (total / (double)input_vector.size());
}
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Pass the vector by reference, not by value: `double average(std::vector<double> &input_vector)` -- this code is making a copy of the entire vector, every time. Oy.

Comment: Also, use `operator[]` instead of `at`. Or just use `std::accumulate` directly. That can be parallelized automatically in C++17 btw. (Also with libstdc++, but that's not what you're using.)

Comment: Thank you both for your tips. I will definitely keep them in mind in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the definition of arithmetic mean is `sum( n ) / count( n )` you don't need to store every value of `n` in order to recompute the running mean, you only need the current `sum` and the current `count`, like so:

```
double runningMean(double newValue) {
    static double sum = 0;
    static double count = 0;

    count++;
    sum += newValue;

    return sum / count;
}
```

No `vector` needed at all.